# RxJS on complete callback not executed with mergeMap

Tags: reactive-programming, observable, rxjs5

I am wondering why the onComplete callback in the example bellow never gets executed. The next callback is executed as expected. If I throw an error inside the observable created by foo, the error callback also gets executed. Only the complete callback does not get executed.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/punoridajo/edit?html,js,console,output

```
let button = document.getElementById('click-me');

let clicks$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

let foo = () => new Rx.Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  observer.next(3);
  observer.next(4);
  observer.next(5);
  console.log('Calling on complete')
  observer.complete();
})

clicks$
  .mergeMap(() => foo())
  .subscribe(
    e => console.log(e),
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.info('Completed') //Never gets executed
)
```

Everything works as expected When I subscribe directly to the Observable returned by foo. Is it not possible to call complete inside an Observable in association with mergeMap, switchMap or concatMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because click$ observable is not completed. Use take(1) or something to complete it.

```
clicks$
.take(1)
.mergeMap(() => foo())
.subscribe(
   e => console.log(e),
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.info('Completed') //Never gets executed
)
```